# Find which substring is contained in string with Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, find

I have a char variable called "condition". The content of this variable is something like:
"21331-54-task-5da1-6256853-35-1-3.mp4".

I need to determine which one of the following characters is contained in the name: 25, 35, 45.
I tried with contains(), but this only tells me whether one of these is contained or not in condition. It doesn't tell me which one is contained.

I also tried:

> strToFind  = {'25', '35', '45'};
>
> pos = strfind(strToFind, condition)

but it gives me the following result:

> pos =
>
> 1×3 cell array
>
> ```
> {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
> ```

Any suggestion on how to solve this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(condition, strToFind, 'once'))
```

will give a logical array the same size as `strToFind`, telling if each of the strings in `strToFind` is present in `condition`.

You can also use

```
cellfun(@(x) contains(condition, x), strToFind)
```